Interlisp Medley: LITATOM 'streams' no longer supported
I am trying to print string text to file in interlisp medley. Here is the code:
(OUTPUT)
> T
(SETQ OUT (OPENSTREAM 'output.TEDIT 'OUTPUT))
> <Output stream ...>
(OUTPUT OUT)
> T
(PRIN1 'lalala OUT)
> lalala

but the file 'output.TEDIT' (and its new versions) are still empty. and if I try this:
(PRIN1 'lalala (OPENFILE 'output.TEDIT 'OUT))

it pop up a 'INTERLISP ERROR' window saying "LITATOM 'streams' no longer supported."
How can I print to file in Interlisp Medley?

How is this different from your earlier question?

Get into the habit of reading manuals; "Because of buffering, the contents of a file open for output are not guaranteed to be written to the actual physical file device until CLOSEF is called. Buffered data can be forced out to a file without closing the file by using the function FORCEOUTPUT (Chapter 25)."
